# Iframe data communication

Tags: reactjs, iframe

Lets say I have two distinct, very minimalistic react applications.
App1 that runs on localhost port 3000 and App2 that runs on localhost port 3001.

App1 only has an input type text.
App2 has a button and an iframe that points to App1 (you can see App1 inside of App2).

When App2's button is clicked I want to change the value of App1's input to "John Doe".
I was able to achieve this by sending "John Doe" via postMessage to App1.
The thing is , i would like to acheive the same but without having to add code to app1 , so without "window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {... etc".

Is this feasable? I have tried to target the id of the input in App1 directly from App2 but that seems to be a dead end since it is not the same DOM. Any idea on how I can tackle this?

Once I get that figured out , I would then like to listen from App2 the value of the input in App1 and trigger for example a console.log(newValue) on each value change.
Could this be done strictly from App2 without altering the code in App1?